# Inconvenientes con la función MessageBox de C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cordial saludo , espero se encuentren bien.
Poe medio de la presente necesito preguntarles si por favor me pueden indicar por que razón al incluir dentro de un formulario la instrucción MessageBox.Show

Me muestra el siguiente error:
The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context

teniendo en cuenta que dentro del mismo proyecto, pero  en otro formulario incluyo la misma instruccion MessageBox.Show y no tengo problema alguno.

Muchas gracias por cualquier colaboración.

Comment: el tag asp.net No tiene nada que ver con windows form

Answer (score 0):

Debes revisar las referencias en los usings y poner

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

De esta forma podrás usar los mensajes

También puede pasar que no tengas en el proyecto la referencia a la dll
System.Windows.Forms.dll, para ello debes añadirla yendo al explorador de soluciones(donde mismo tienes las clases de tu proyecto), vas al ítem References clic derecho sobre el, opción Add referentes, buscas la librería y la añades, entonces después la agregas también a través del using

Comment: Mira a ver, espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias, vale mencionar que yo inclui dicho using al principio del código, y me sigue mostrando el mismo error.

Comment: Revisa lo nuevo que puse